# ssh failed to copy local files to the server

Tags: ssh, scp

I have connected to the server and I am root user，but my command failed

```
scp -p 10010 ~/Desktop/usb.sh root@localhost:/
```

Error:

> ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: I changed lowercase p to uppercase P, it works，thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a *capital* `P` (`-P`) to specify a port, from the man page:
[scp (1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp):

> -P port

> Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host. **Note that this option is written with a capital 'P'**, because -p is already reserved for preserving the times and modes of the file in [rcp(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rcp).

---

Also, ensure you user can write to the document root (`/`), you can always write to your home folder: (`root@localhost:/root/`)

---

Fixed command:

```
scp -P 10010 ~/Desktop/usb.sh root@localhost:/
```